# Update Column from Table With Data Updated in another table

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-apex, apex

I have two tables

```
   CREATE TABLE  "LOCKER_AUDIT" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "PAINT_SHOP" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "LOCKER_#" NUMBER, 
        "LOCKER_LOCATION" VARCHAR2(255), 
        "DEPT" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "ASSOCIATE_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
        "NAME__CINTAS_" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "AUDIT_NOTES_" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "LOCKER_TRANSFER_REQUESTED" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "TERM_EMPLOYEE" VARCHAR2(255), 
        "LOCKER_ISSUE" VARCHAR2(255), 
         PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
     USING INDEX  ENABLE
      )
     /
```

And

```
    CREATE TABLE  "LOCKER_TERM_LIST" 
             (  "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  
    NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
            "CLEANING_DATE" DATE, 
             "NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
             "PAINT_SHOP" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
             "LOCKER_NUMBER" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
             "LOCKER_LOCATION" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
             "NOTES" VARCHAR2(255), 
             "FUNCTION" VARCHAR2(255), 
             "SIZE_REMOVED" VARCHAR2(255), 
             "EMAIL_SENT_DATE" DATE, 
             "REMOVED_FROM_LOCKER_LIST" VARCHAR2(255), 
             "NOTES__UPDATED_NOTES_" VARCHAR2(255), 
              PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
      )
      /
```

If NAME_CINTAS_ from Locker audit table is the same as NAME from Locker Term List Table, I want the column 'Term_Employee' to update to a value of 'yes' in the Locker Audit table

What is the best way to do this, I tried playing with triggers and ended up not getting anywhere. I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

`Merge` looks pretty simple to me:

```
merge into locker_audit a
using locker_term_list b
on (a.name_cintas_ = b.name)
when matched then update set
  a.term_employee = 'yes';
```